# Android volley Multi-part form-data request with Persian characters receive question mark on server side

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, android-volley, multipartform-data

I have big problem with volley.
I want to send to server my multi-part data with one image and some 
text in Persian Character set with utf-8 encoding but when i send data to server , server give all my Persian characters question mark. !!!!
Can anybody help me?

I wrote a method to upload my profile data.

```
public synchronized void updateUserProfile(ProfileBundle bundle, String tagName, final UpdateUserInfoListener listener) {
    final String url = Constants.NETWORK.MAIN_URL + "/accounts/update-profile/";
    try {

        Charset chars = CharsetUtils.get("UTF-8");
        StringBody userNameBody = new StringBody(bundle.getUserName(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        StringBody firstNameBody = new StringBody(bundle.getFirstName(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        StringBody lastNameBody = new StringBody(bundle.getLastName(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        StringBody phoneBody = new StringBody(bundle.getPhone(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addPart("first_name", firstNameBody)
                .addPart("last_name", lastNameBody)
                .addPart("phone", phoneBody)
                .addPart("username", userNameBody)
                .addTextBody("file", "")
                .setCharset(chars)
                .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                .build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            try {
                UserInfoModel model = new Gson().fromJson(fixString(s), UserInfoModel.class);
                listener.onUpdate(true, model, s);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new MyResponseListener(ctx) {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            super.onErrorResponse(volleyError);
            try {
                String str = new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data);
                listener.onUpdate(false, null, str);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            initHeaders(headers);
            headers.put("Content-Type", entity.getContentType().getValue());
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {

                entity.writeTo(bos);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bos.toByteArray();
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            String str = entity.getContentType().getValue();
            return str;
        }

    };

    request.setTag(tagName);
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode each Persian character

String yourEncodedData = URLEncoder.encode(yourData,"UTF-8");

and decode it in the server side

yourData = URLDecoder.decode(yourEncodedData, "UTF-8");

Comment: No this does not work well. i think volly in background ignore my charset and do it in it's own way. :)

Comment: I've got the same problem (but with german special chars). Do you finally get a solution for this problem?

Comment: If you still got the problem I was able to solve it with the following code: `dataOutputStream.write(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));`As you can see I did not use Multipartentity, but a custom VolleyMultipartRequest we found at stackoverflow. Maybe it's interesting for you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here is my solution:

```
     String enName="",enCity="",enSubcity="";
    try {
        enName = URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8");
        enCity = URLEncoder.encode(city,"UTF-8");
        enName = URLEncoder.encode(subcity,"UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

just use encoded Strings in  you url.